# PythonTeX connecting to .accdb with python module and making adjustment to the output

Tags: python, pythontex

I am working on connecting `TeX` with `MS Access` database. Great option for my workflow seems to be `PythonTeX`, since that for beginner in `TeX and Python`, like me, it is pretty easy to use and work with (cheers to Mr. Poore).

I am connecting to `testdb.accdb` with following code. `testdb.accdb` contains only one table, `testTable`, with fields: `ID`, `testText`. Lets say its contents are (in `.csv` format; please inform me, if ti is valid to somehow attach `testdb.accdb` or exported `.csv` from it to make easier recreating my issue):

ID, testText

1, This is going to be pretty long test.

2, This is going to be even longer text that could span more than a few lines, and actually, real cases can even span multiple paragraphs.

Python code to connect to `testdb.accdb` and print values stored in testTable:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=Z:\Databáze\Jazyk Access a SQL\MWE\MWE3\testdb.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from testTable')

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

In `IDLE`, this outputs the contents of each row with line break (is it the `\r\n`??), but if I put the same in `PythonTeX` `pyblock` and visualize it with `\printpythontex`, I get no such linebreaks, which makes reading the output very complicated.

How can I achieve the same output as is in `IDLE` with `PythonTeX`?

Full `MWE`:

```
% arara:  lualatex

\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright] {book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

Test of printing information from \verb|.accdb| to Python\TeX :

\begin{pyblock}
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=Z:\Databáze\Jazyk Access a SQL\MWE\MWE3\testdb.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from testTable')

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
\end{pyblock}

\vskip 1 cm

\printpythontex

\end{document}
```

PS: I am considering regular expressions, but I havent got that far in my python studying yet, and I found out that a lot of people has strong feelings about using regex... Also preferable solution is modification of the output from python side, not from TeX side.

Comment: `\printpythontex` takes various modes as optional argument.  Have you tried playing with them?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thank you for your comment Mr. Swann. I must have missed that in documentation, I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some sense PythonTeX takes the printed output you generate and inputs this into LaTeX as if the Python output would be pasted verbatim into the LaTeX document. That means in your case that the printed output contains linebreaks but LaTeX does not insert a linebreak into your output document for a single linebreak in the input paragraph.

So if you want to typeset the printed python output in LaTeX one option is to convert your strings to follow LaTeX conventions (raw formatting option) or use the verbatim environment (`\printpythontex[verbatim]`):

```
% arara:  lualatex

\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright] {book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

Test of printing information from Python\TeX :

\begin{pyblock}

test_string = "This is a test string with \nlinebreaks."
print(test_string)

test_string_tex = r"This is a test string with \\linebreaks\\using LaTeX notation."
print(test_string_tex)

test_string_double = "This is a test string with two consecutive \n\nlinebreaks \n\n which start a new paragraph."
print(test_string_double)

\end{pyblock}

\vskip 1 cm

\printpythontex

\printpythontex[verbatim]

\end{document}
```

This typesets to 
[image]

Comment: Hello Alexander. Thank you for your answer. It brings me closer to my goal, but still not entirely, because (if I understood right) it requires the user of .accdb to input TeX code in field values. I cant achieve that, I have db users that dont work with TeX.
Printing verbatim is restraining, because I lose TeX typesetting of values (long strings). I look into \printpythontex in doc again as suggested by Mr. Swann.

Comment: @TomášKruliš That the database contains TeX formatting is one option, but that is not required. You are free to change the strings returned from the database before printing them out. For example a simple string replace in python of `\n` to `\n\n` would lead to new paragraphs in the output.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Alexander, that was indeed my question. Would you please add before mentioned commentary into body of your answer? Also, code snippet would be most helpful (would it have to be done by simple string.replace() or re.sub() ?) as mentioned for example on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475885/python-replace-regex

Comment: @TomášKruliš: While there are many ways a starting point could look like this: `test_string_reformatted = test_string.replace("\n", "\n\n")
print(test_string_reformatted)`.